# When Sims wake up, 'zzz' still show above their heads

Tags: the-sims-4

In The Sims 4 (Xbox One), I keep having this problem. When my Sims wake up, they continue to have 'zzz' over their heads.

Comment: Adding an image would help us greatly towards understanding the problem better.

Comment: Does this happen with every Sim in your game? Or only certains Sims? And how long does it last, do the "zzz's" never go away?

Comment: Only in some games

Comment: And the zzz’s never go away!